# Java Check Vaild File

Tags: java

Please help, I need help on how to check for valid file names.

Here is part of my program...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BookstoreInventory
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
        //Vaiable declartions
        int edition, quanity;
        double pricePerBook;
        String isbn, author, title, publisherCode;
        int totalQuant = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double totalValue = 0;
        double sumOfPriceBook = 0;

        //Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get the file name from the user
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the file: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Open the file and set delimiters
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        inputFile.useDelimiter("_|/|\\r?\\n");
    }
}
```

So in my program I'm not sure how I would check to see if it's a valid file. For example, when the user enters "inventory" for the name of the file this will produce an error because the filename needs the .txt so the user should have entered "inventory.txt". So is there a way to adding the .txt to the name they entered? Or how do I check to see if a file is valid? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use [String#endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) and check if the user input a string ending with ".txt".

Comment: [`File.canRead()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead--) with `if (file.canRead())`?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by ***valid***. Do you mean that what they enter has the format of a valid file name? Or do you mean that they enter the name of a file that actually exists? PLease specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (!fileName.trim().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
    fileName+= ".txt";
}
```

Also, if you want to know if the file already exists or not:

```
File file = new File(filename);
// If file doesn't exist then close application...
if (!file.exists()) { System.exist(0); }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the user's input string by adding `.txt`. It should work.